# Indy 10 'SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry' error and flag SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY

Tags: openssl, c++builder, indy10

For some time, we've been encountering some `'error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry'` errors when synchronizing some of our email accounts (not all email accounts, even though they connect to the same server and are connected to the same local network) when trying to send some emails using Indy 10 in C++Builder 10.3 Rio.

Please, note that this issue has also been reported in the app version built with C++Builder XE5 and C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo.

After many research, including reading some posts on this very website,
as well as this very useful documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_mode.html, I concluded that this error could be fixed by setting some specific modes to the OpenSSL component: `SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE` and/or `SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER`.

I wanted to know which mode was used in Indy, so I downloaded the sources from GitHub, and worked my way in the files so that I finally came across the file `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas`, which showcases line 3300:

```
SSL_CTX_set_mode(fContext, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
```

My question is, would it solve the `'bad write entry'` errors on our impacted emails if I modify the code this way?

```
SSL_CTX_set_mode(fContext, SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE);
SSL_CTX_set_mode(fContext, SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER);
SSL_CTX_set_mode(fContext, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
```

Also, I'm guessing that there must be side effects at some point if it wasn't done this way in the first place. What should I expect?

Comment: What is the actual operation that causes the "bad write retry" error? is it an `SSL_write()` call, or maybe `SSL_shutdown()`? Do you have a call stack leading up to the error? Offhand, I don't think enabling those additional modes should have any side effects, as Indy is already setup to retry failed `SSL_write()` calls using the same input buffer without modifying it, so I don't know why OpenSSL is complaining about the "bad write retry" error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your fast answer!  Unfortunately I don't have a call stack for this, I don't have this error in my environnement.  I don't know if this is raised by a `SSL_write()` or a `SSL_shutdown()` call, but when this error is raised during the sending of an email, the email is not sent. Would it indicate that this error happens during `SSL_write()`? This is indeed surprising that the error is raised while the call is retried with the exact same parameters, in this context I don't see how the 2 flags I wanted to add could change anything to the issue...